# Get the top of an element and make an operation

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get the top style of an element and then subtract 40px but i can't.

The element has the following styles:
https://gyazo.com/174dba750bdc1df074c5bda7bf710d7f

And i'm using jquery to get the top of the element (it doesn't return 492, it returns me 487 and don't know why):

```js
var x = jQuery(".modules-mobile .element-wrap:nth-child(2)").position().top;
var t = `${jQuery('.modules-mobile .element-wrap:nth-child(2)').position().top - 40}px`;
jQuery(".modules-mobile .element-wrap:nth-child(2)").css('top', (Math.round(x) - 40) + 'px');
jQuery(".modules-mobile .element-wrap:nth-child(2)").css('top', t);
```

If i console.log the var x it returns me this:
https://gyazo.com/e9bc1f8443ab541c0d4fbb6f0a124ab0

If i use this it returns me an 'auto':

```js
jQuery(".modules-mobile .element-wrap:nth-child(2)").css("top");
```

also, no one of 2 applies the styles

Thanks

Comment: have you tried this: jQuery(".modules-mobile .element-wrap:nth-child(2)").css('top', (Math.round(x) - 40) + 'px'); to set the top style of the element.

Comment: Yes, i edited the post wth what i tried and no one applies the styles

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle and put your working code for demo? None of your code snippets are working which you have added above.

Comment: As @maverickosama92 says, we need to see the relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see the problem in action. However don't use jsfiddle - your quextion should include all the code so please add a snippet directly in your question (using the button on the editor toolbar). You can add a jsfiddle *as well* if you like, but your question must include the code.